# IndexOutOfBounds - what can be the source of error?

Tags: android, sqlite

I have a custom listview with call log info (name, phoneNum, date&time, duration). On a single click on an item sometimes there is error:

> *java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 2, size is 0*

on the line marked below in the code.

The app is on the market and I haven't met this error, nor can I think of a way to create it. I need help to find out what may be the cause.

This is the code:

```
lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {

        Toast.makeText(Calllogs.this, "short click: " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

        if (arr_calllog_name2.size() > 0) arr_calllog_name2.clear();
        if (arr_calllog_phone2.size() > 0) arr_calllog_phone2.clear();
        if (arr_calllog_type2.size() > 0) arr_calllog_type2.clear();
        if (arr_calllog_duration2.size() > 0) arr_calllog_duration2.clear();
        if (arr_calllog_date2.size() > 0) arr_calllog_date2.clear();
        if (arr_calllog_contactid2.size() > 0) arr_calllog_contactid2.clear();

        HotOrNot info2 = new HotOrNot(Calllogs.this);
        info2.open();

        //Some user selected options like view only the incoming, outgoing calls, sort by alphabet or date... 
        LoadView(); 
        LoadSort(); 
        LoadSortBy();

        if (loadedview == 4) {
            if (loadedsortby == 1) //sort by alphabet
            {
                cursorL = info2.getAllTitlesViewSort2Date(loadedsort, d1, d2);
            }
            else if (loadedsortby == 2) //sort by date
            {
                cursorL = info2.getAllTitlesViewSort4Date(loadedsort, d1, d2);
            }
        } else {
            if (loadedsortby == 1) //sort by alphabet
            {
                cursorL = info2.getAllTitlesViewSort1Date(loadedview, loadedsort, d1, d2);
            }
            else if (loadedsortby == 2) //sort by date
            {
                cursorL = info2.getAllTitlesViewSort3Date(loadedview, loadedsort, d1, d2);
            }
        }

         if (cursorL.moveToFirst()){
             do{
                  arr_calllog_name2.add(cursorL.getString(1));
                  arr_calllog_phone2.add(cursorL.getString(2));
                  arr_calllog_type2.add(cursorL.getString(3));
                  arr_calllog_duration2.add(cursorL.getString(4));
                  arr_calllog_date2.add(cursorL.getString(5));
                  arr_calllog_contactid2.add(cursorL.getString(6));
            }while (cursorL.moveToNext());
        }

        info2.close();

        name = arr_calllog_name2.get(position); //error line
        phone = arr_calllog_phone2.get(position);
        type = arr_calllog_type2.get(position);
        duration = arr_calllog_duration2.get(position);
        date = arr_calllog_date2.get(position);
        contactid = arr_calllog_contactid2.get(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
        intent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phone));
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

So at first there is a listview with items. The user clicks on an item then the activity force closes. CursorL is defined at the beginning of the code (Cursor cursorL).
The     `LoadView(); LoadSort(); LoadSortBy();` functions sort the list by alphabet or date, showing only the incoming and/or outgoing calls etc. At first they must give a value, because I set default values for them:

```
public void LoadView() {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    loadedview = sharedPreferences.getInt("view", 4);
}

public void LoadSort() {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    loadedsort = sharedPreferences.getString("sort", "DESC");
}

public void LoadSortBy() {
    sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager
            .getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext());
    loadedsortby = sharedPreferences.getInt("sortby", 2);
}
```

The `loadedsortby` variable can have only two values: 1 and 2, I checked. The `loadedview` can have only 4 values: 1,2,3,4.

All I can think of is the `cursorL` and thus the `arr_calllog_name2` arraylist is somehow empty, but I don't know how it is possible.

As an example I post one of the queries that populate the cursorL:

```
public Cursor getAllTitlesViewSort1Date(int view, String sort, String date1, String date2) {
        return ourDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + DATABASE_TABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_DATE + " BETWEEN '" + date1 + "'" + " AND '" + date2 + "'" + " AND " + KEY_TYPE + " = '" + view + "'" + " ORDER BY " + KEY_NAME + " COLLATE NOCASE " + sort, null);
    }
```

Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: check this link. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/IndexOutOfBoundsException.html

Comment: I know what the error means. That's why I said that there are e.g. 5 items in the list, then the user clicks on the 2nd, it gives an error, because the cursorL is empty.

Comment: @erdomester problem is with your query statement, `cursorL.moveToFirst()` is getting false. check the query.

Comment: The problem is, cursorL cannot be empty. When the listview is populated, the same query (getAllTitlesViewSort1Date, getAllTitlesViewSort2Date...) is used. Since the list items cannot be modified, added, or removed, it must have the same values. And since the listview is populated with one of these cursors, cursorL cannot be wrong or empty.

Comment: i think in your case better approach would be to keep the cursor which is used in the listview adapter in Class field and then use this field to calculate arr_calllog_name2, rather than querying it everytime onclick, maybe the loadedview, loadedsortby variables not in sync with the cursor used to populate listview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using this...

```
if (cursorL.moveToFirst()){
             do{
                  arr_calllog_name2.add(cursorL.getString(1));
                  arr_calllog_phone2.add(cursorL.getString(2));
                  arr_calllog_type2.add(cursorL.getString(3));
                  arr_calllog_duration2.add(cursorL.getString(4));
                  arr_calllog_date2.add(cursorL.getString(5));
                  arr_calllog_contactid2.add(cursorL.getString(6));
            }while (cursorL.moveToNext());
        }
```

Try

```
cursorL.getCount()
```

If the count is not 0, then do this...

```
        cursorL.moveToFirst();
        while(!cursorL.isAfterLast())
        {
            arr_calllog_name2.add(cursorL.getString(1));
                  arr_calllog_phone2.add(cursorL.getString(2));
                  arr_calllog_type2.add(cursorL.getString(3));
                  arr_calllog_duration2.add(cursorL.getString(4));
                  arr_calllog_date2.add(cursorL.getString(5));
                  arr_calllog_contactid2.add(cursorL.getString(6));
            cursorL.moveToNext();
        }
        cursorL.close();
```